# Need Assistance With Inserting New Child XML Element With PHP

Tags: php, xml, file, dom, insert

I've been browsing around for hours now and there is no simple explaination or demonstration of how to insert a new child element into an XML file and then save the XML file.

Here is the XML Tree.. (very simple)

```
< book > 

    <chapter> 
        <title>Everyday Italian</title> 
        <year>2005</year> 
    </chapter> 
    <chapter> 
        <title>Harry Potter</title> 
        <year>2005</year> 
    </chapter> 
    <chapter> 
        <title>XQuery Kick Start</title> 
        <year>2003</year>   
    </chapter> 

< / book >
```

...
I would deeply appreciate any help with this. Once again to recap, I have a PHP file and it its goal is to insert a new "chapter" with specifieid "title" and "year" and then save the new file (basically overwriting the book.xml file)

Answer (score 1):

There is an example inside the php-manual which gives you  all informations you need:
http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php

The methods you need:

- **DOMDocument->load()**
    //load xml from a file
- **DOMDocument->createElement()**
  //create a element-node
- **DOMDocument->createTextNode()**
  //create a textNode
- **DOMNode->appendChild()**
  //append one node to another
- **DOMDocument->save()**
  //save XML into a file

,

```
<?php
  //create a document
  $doc=new DOMDocument;
  //load the file
  $doc->load('book.xml');
  //create chapter-element
  $chapter=$doc->createElement('chapter');
  //create title-element
  $title=$doc->createElement('title');
  //insert text to the title
  $title->appendChild($doc->createTextNode('new title for a new chapter'));
  //create year-element
  $year=$doc->createElement('year');
  //insert text to the year
  $year->appendChild($doc->createTextNode('new year for a new chapter'));
  //append title and year to the chapter
  $chapter->appendChild($title);  
  $chapter->appendChild($year);  
  //append the chapter to the root-element
  $doc->documentElement->appendChild($chapter);  
  //save it into the file
  $doc->save('book.xml');
?>
```

Comment: Yeah I visited that link and the example confused me a bit. So basically.. Open up the xml file, make the path to create a new element inside the parent node, and then two other nodes in that new element along with the text nodes with their values, and then append that entire new element to the root? (appending new node to the parent node)?

Comment: I put an working example into my answer. There is a easier method using a fragment(but this is not a official DOM-standard and a little bit dirty in my mind): http://de.php.net/manual/en/domdocumentfragment.appendxml.php

Comment: Works perfectly now thanks Dr. Molle. All I needed was a more clear example for this so I could know the basic structure for this.

Comment: I tried to do this, but it is not actually writing anything in my file :(